# Iteratively altering data frames in R

Tags: r

I receive 3 data frames (training, validation, and test) containing data with the same variables. I'd prefer them not to be contained within a list so that I can refer to them neatly as `trn`, `vld`, and `tst` as opposed to `list[[1]]` etc.

I need to drop variables from all the datasets. Is there a way to iteratively process without first creating a list, iterating, then re-creating the data frames from the list? i.e. I'm currently doing like to do something like:

```
trn <- read.csv("training_split_60pct.csv")
vld <- read.csv("validation_split_20pct.csv")
tst <- read.csv("test_split_20pct.csv")

# a list of variables to drop
drops <- c("ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR")

dfRawList <- list(trn, vld, tst)
dfList <- lapply(dfRawList, function(df) df[,!(names(df) %in% drops)])
names(dfList) <- c("trn", "vld", "tst")

trn <- dfList[["trn"]]
vld <- dfList[["vld"]]
tst <- dfList[["tst"]]
```

But I'd like to be able to do:

```
trn <- read.csv("training_split_60pct.csv")
vld <- read.csv("validation_split_20pct.csv")
tst <- read.csv("test_split_20pct.csv")

# a list of variables to drop
drops <- c("ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR")

for (df in c('trn', 'vld', 'tst')){
    df <- lapply(df, function(df) df[,!(names(df) %in% drops)])
}
```

Of course, this just creates one data frame with the `tst` data.

Comment: You seem to know the recommended way in R. I suggest to use it.

Comment: @shadow: thanks for answers. I'm quite new to R so apologies. Are there some examples as to why this is recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `assign` and `get`. But I would recommend to use lists and `lapply` as you are currently doing.

```
for (df in c("trn", "vld", "tst")){
  assign(df, get(df)[, !names(get(df)) %in% drops])
}
```